# Couldn't align footer(bottom), left, and content panel(side by side with fixed height)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two divs (left, content panel) side by side with fixed height and then footer beneath it. It seems my css fixed heigh property 60% seems to be ignored.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <!-- Header starts-->
    <div class="header">
    Header
    </div>
    <!-- Header ends-->
    <!-- Left panel starts-->
    <div class="leftPanel">
    Left panel
    </div>
    <!-- Left panel -->
    <!-- Login panel starts-->
    <div class="contentPanel">
    </div>
    <!-- Login panel -->
    <!-- Footer starts -->
    <div class="footer">
    This is footer
    </div>
    <!-- Footer ends -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
.header {
    background-color:red;
    height:20%;
    text-align:center;
}
.contentPanel {
    background-color:green;
    height:60%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:70%;
}
.leftPanel {
    background-color:#FF00FF;
    height:60%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:30%;
    top:20%;
}
.footer {
    background-color:orange;
    height:20%;
    top: 80%;
    width:100%;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

*This is what I get:*
http://jsfiddle.net/sas/yn1p468u/4/

*This is what I want:*

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing up `position` and `display` properties. Valid `position` values are things like `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, etc. while valid `display` properties are things like `block`, `inline-block`, `table`, etc.

Comment: Even when I change the position to relative, still it doesn't seems to be aligning the way want.

Comment: that's a different issue; I'm just letting you know that your properties mentioned above won't be doing anything because they aren't the right values for those properties. It's like trying to use a banana as a telephone.

Comment: Percentage heights are based off the containing blocks height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `top` property on `.footer` which will only work if you have a absolute or relative positioned element. However, this ain't the problem.

You "say" to `.leftPanel` that it should take 60% of the height, but since the parent doesn't have a height declared, it will only take the space it needs.

The solution is to add a height to the `.parent` aswell to the `body` and `html` tag.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.parent {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You also need to add a `clear: both` to the footer, while the elements in front of it float.

Also check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/yn1p468u/8/).

Answer (score 1):

Put the left panel and content inside a container and set that as a block. So you've got:

```
<div class="header">
    // Header
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftPanel">
        // Left panel
    </div>
    <div class="contentPanel">
        // Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    // Footer content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header, .container, .footer {display:block;width:100%;}
.leftPanel, .contentPanel {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
.leftPanel {width:30%;}
.contentPanel {width:70%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Percentages does not work very well in heights, so try using px or em.

Also, there is no such as thing as "position: inline-block;"

what you probably would is to put:

- display: inline-block;

and

- position: relative;

and, you need to put clear: left on your footer, or insert a div that clears, right above your footer.

Comment: The reason percentages "don't work well" in heights is that they need their parent element or containing block to have an explicit (non-percentage) height, as @LinkinTED says in their answer.